# How can I confirm shared disks between two or more servers in linux?

Tags: linux, disk

I'd like to know a way to check if the disks in one server is the same in the second server (shared disks).

Is this way correct? (compare major:minor numbers).

Server 01:

```
[root@server01 ~]# ls -l /dev/dm-90
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 253, 90 Apr 10 03:41 /dev/dm-90
[root@server01 ~]#
```

Server 02:

```
[root@server02 ~]# ls -l /dev/dm-90
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 90 Apr 10 04:09 /dev/dm-90
[root@server02 ~]#
```

Comment: Unless you provide more information on how the disks are shared, nobody can provide a precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO - no, major number is OK, it give you the type of device (based on the number of driver, defined in kernel), but minor can be different, depend on how many devices of this type you have on particular server. SO they can differ.

You can try to compare the hash of fist 1MB on each server:

```
dd if=/dev/dm-90 bs=512 count=2048|sha1sum
```

But this can give false results if these disks are quite "dynamic" (a lot of write operations)

Other possible way if you have filesystem on these disks (and it is mounted) is to create (once) one file:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/mount/point/of/disk/1MBfile bs=512 count=2048
```

and then on both servers compare the hash of the file:

```
sha1sum /mount/point/of/disk/1MBfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Major/minor numbers are non-persistent and dynamically assigned by the OS locally, so they are **definitely not suitable** for identifying a disk across servers.

A better solution would be to verify the presumed-unique features of the disk itself, like the disk serial number, disk WWID (if available), and if the disk is initialized with a filesystem, the filesystem UUID (or equivalent).

On modern Linux systems:

```
lsblk -o +MODEL,SERIAL,WWN,UUID
```

should display enough information to achieve a pretty strong confidence on most disk types.

Note that verifying just the filesystem UUID is not enough, as the disk/LUN might actually not be the same, but a storage-system-level snapshot or clone of the original disk.

If the shared disks are multipathed, the WWID displayed by device-mapper-multipath tool `multipath -ll` is also a good way to identify storage system LUNs.

(I've understood that the WWID is the main way device-mapper-multipath uses to identify which disk devices are actually redundant paths to the same LUN and which are different LUNs.)